# Laravel need to get username of each comment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, laravel-5.4

My problem with getting the commenter is that I save the user Id when it comments and I return all comments below the post, but when I try to return the username as well, Laravel gives an error, I guess it is becouse it doesn't know for which user id it should return the username from users table. Currently the controller for comments is as following:

```
$comments = DB::select("Select * from comments where article_id = $articleID");
```

I get the `$articleID` vie the route in orther to find the article content from database and I use it in ***comments*** table as well to find the comments that belong to the the specific ***article***. But when I try to for example

```
$commenter = User::where('id', $comments->user_id)->first();
```

it fails. I tried a few version of this type SQL commands but does not work. Because it doesn't know which commenter I'm talking about (I guess). Do you have any idea about how I can do it?

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is call `get()` on your `DB::select()`. So it would be `$comments = DB::select("Select * from comments where article_id = $articleID")->get();`

Then I think you would receive a collection, not a comments object, so you would need to iterate the array calling `$commenter = User::find($comments->user_id)->get();`

Comment: ohhh yeah I know that. I just wrote that code for smaple. I tried bunch of things from both laravel and mysql. it feels like controller gets confused picking up the right user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a foreach for that. If you need to have the user for each comment, you should iterate over the comments to achieve this. Ex:

```
$comments = DB::select("Select * from comments where article_id = $articleID");

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $commenter = User::where('id', $comment->user_id)->first();
}
```

If you want to get all the users that has comments in the article, you should try to search for users and use the established relationships.
The main idea is something like this.

In the User Model you have to set a relation with comments:

```
public function comments()
{
    $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Then, you can use `whereHas` to search using these relations:

```
$users = User::whereHas('comments', function ($q1) use ($articleId) {
    $q1->where('article_id', $articleId);
})->get();
```

This way you will have a list of all users that have commented on this article.

Comment: What can I retun all the commenters with this? it feels like this is gonna fail but I'm gonna try

Comment: I've added additional information about this... Please take a look.

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Comment: The problem with this is, When I try to ope the page of Post where there is no comments it gives the error ***Undefined variable: commenter*** Now I know I have to check if there is any comments in view and than show the comments, and I do so. the $commenter->username is included inside that if statement as well but, it still gives the error. I tried to check for $commenter insdie the  controller as well but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ok I did something like  ` $commenter = "null";
        if (count($comments) > 0) {
            foreach ($comments as $comment) {
                $commenter = Userprofile::where('id', $comment->user_id)->first();
            }
        }`  and it workes.

Answer (score 2):

Just Forgot all this stuff and follow the below steps :

1) add user relation in Your comment Model :

```
function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id','id');
}
```

2) Then get your comments as below :

```
$comments = Comments::where('artical_id',$articleID)->with('user')->get();
```

3) Then you will get user object in every comments object.

Comment: I never completely understood the models things in laravel

Comment: I tried to add the function into comments but `$this` is underlined and it says    ***Fucntion name must be callable***

Comment: And what is excactly gonna be written in the view? Surely  `{{$comment->username}}` is not gonna return the username from the users table right away, am I right?

Comment: @Nikonah this should work `{{$comment->user->username}}`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I See now. It's a good practice. I will try replacing it with my current one later on. thanks for helping :)